# Corel Painter 2022 eraser not deleting part of layer, just erases it to a white color

Tags: colors

**On Corel Painter 2022**: I have hand-drawn block text (line art) on top of a background image and my desire is to paint those block letters with one wide stroke and then erase the color outside the lines (so as not to cover up the image beneath obviously).

I fail.

So is there not a simple way, once you've painted on a layer with digital watercolor, to erase the bits you don't like to clean it up while also allowing a layer beneath to show? All it does, in this case, is '**paint**' white on top and not actually delete/erase that part of the layer. Once you've painted in Corel Painter, it seems that surface area is there permanently on the layer and you can't delete any parts of it or erase it.

- I have a simple square background layer with yellow color fill.
- I line art some simple block letters on a new layer on top.
- I create another new layer to color inside those block letters.
- I just smear the paint across to save time and because I expect I can '**erase**' the paint outside of the line art.
- I erase but it just turns it white instead of '**deleting**' it so the underlying layer can show through.

I have attached an image to illustrate this.

[image: test image]

Boggles the mind. I can't find any information online, not in forums or anywhere, and I guess it's because nobody uses Corel Painter.

Cheers

Comment: Have you bothered to ask this from Corel?

Comment: Hello, no I haven't. I checked their official Painter forums but the last post was like a year ago?

I did find a small kinda workaround if I set the layer to gel, but need a better solution. Has to be away to just trim off a layer edge.